# How do I add data in the bottom of a JSON column?

Tags: python, json

I would like to add data to a column in my JSON file, without removing what's already there. Meaning I don't want to removing anything that's already there, just adding data in the bottom of the column. How can I do this? With column I mean like this:

```json
{
  "something" : {
    "idk" : "yeah something"
  }
}
```

I wanna add the data below the row in the column.

Comment: what do you mean by "in the bottom of the column"?

Comment: I explained that, in the bottom of the column example I gave, under the last row.

Comment: JSON doesn't have rows or columns.

Comment: JSON columns and rows? ¿?

Comment: What do you call it then?

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

json_str = """
{
  "something" : {
    "idk" : "yeah something"
  }
}"""

d = json.loads(json_str)
print(d)
```

outputs

```
{'something': {'idk': 'yeah something'}}
```

So, you can add new data with:

```
d["something_else"] = {'ikr': 'something else'}
```

The dictionary is now:

```
{'something': {'idk': 'yeah something'}, 'something_else': {'ikr': 'something else'}}
```

So, `json.dumps(d)` results in the string

```
'{
    "something": {
        "idk": "yeah something"
    },
    "something_else": {
        "ikr": "something else"
    }
}'
```

Alternatively, you could add more data to 'something' as follows:

```
d["something"]["more_data"] = "more stuff here"
```

`json.dumps(d)` now results in the string

```
'{
    "something":{
        "idk": "yeah something",
        "more_data": "more stuff here"
    },
    "something_else": {
        "ikr": "something else"
    }
}'
```